# object doesn't support property or method datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to put a datepicker in my page and getting this error. I already searched and looked for other answers to this error, but couldn't find any.

Without the **FOR BOOTSTRAP** part, it works; but with it, I am getting this error. What is the reason behind this and how can I fix this?

Here is my `index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Chart")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ENOCTA DASHBOARD</title>

    <!-- FOR DATEPICKER -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>

    <!-- FOR BOOTSTRAP -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does your jquery-ui contain the datepicker widget?

Comment: I don't know. How can I check?

Comment: when you download jquery-ui (http://jqueryui.com/download/), you have the possibility to exlude widgets/components which you don't use. Maybe try downloading a complete jquery-ui, or search the jquery-ui.js for the datepicker widget.

Comment: I downloaded the packet and added `.js` & `.css` files to the project, also changed the `Bundleconfig.css` according to that. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 versions of jQuery on the page, the jQuery UI datepicker hangs itself into the first version, then the second one overwrites the first one and thus the datepicker is not available when the `DOMContentReady` event is fired. The solution is to move the second jquery include up and remove the first one:

```
<!-- FOR DATEPICKER -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>

<!-- FOR BOOTSTRAP -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```