# Vitalets datepicker "Object does not support property or method datepicker"

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to plug in the Vitalets datepicker into my solution but whenever I try to do so it is returning the error "Object does not support property or method datepicker".

I have looked around online and so far the issue seems to be that two different versions of jquery have been loaded, but I have checked and that doesn't seem to be the case in this project.

My code goes like:

**VIEW**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label for="UserName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="UserName" name="=UserName" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label for="datepicker">Start Date</label>
            <input type="text" value="02-16-2012" id="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script src="~/Content/vitalets-bootstrap-datepicker-c7af15b/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    //Initialise any date pickers
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
    });
});
```

If someone could help direct me in the right way I would really appreciate it!

**EDIT**

These are the css and js files i'm loading into my project via the layout page:

```
<link href="~/Content/colour-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<link href="~/Content/vitalets-bootstrap-datepicker-c7af15b/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-toggle-master/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/vitalets-bootstrap-datepicker-c7af15b/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap-toggle-master/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please follow [object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582011/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-datepicker)

Comment: @TechVision I saw that post while looking around for a solution, but I'm only loading one version of jQuery (1.10.2). I've updated my post to show the files i'm loading in to my layout file